# How to Fix Google Adsense Issue: Site Behavior: Navigation Issue?

Tags: adsense

Facing this issue on Google Adsense.

Your site isn’t ready to show ads

We’ve found some policy violations on your site which means your site isn’t ready to show ads yet.

Site Behavior: Navigation

As stated in our Program policies, sites or apps displaying Google ads should provide substantial and useful information to the user. Users should be able to easily navigate through the site or app to find what products, goods, or services are promised. Examples of misguided navigation include, but are not limited to:

False claims of downloadable or streaming content

Linking to content that does not exist

Redirecting users to irrelevant and/or misleading webpages

Text on a page unrelated to the topic and/or business model of the website.

Website: https://theblackfridaycoupons.com/

Please help me and indicate what's wrong on the site.

Tried changing content, menu, removed 404 pages but nothing worked.